# Check if a Connector has the EndConnectedShape VBA PPT

Tags: vba, shapes, connector, powerpoint-2013

I need to check if a Connector is really connected to a Shape, in other words, does it have any Shape returned by EndConnectedShape. So far I have this, but it gives me an error: Permission denied:

```
Sub test()
    Dim oSh, mySh As Shape
    smth = "SomeName"

    For Each oSh In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        If oSh.Connector And oSh.Name = smth Then
            ' In the NEXT line the following error is returned:
            ' oSh.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape = <Permission denied>
            Set mySh = oSh.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape
            If Not IsEmpty(mySh) Then
                oSh.ConnectorFormat.EndConnectedShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next oSh

End Sub
```

There must be something very simple, but I can't figure out what I miss. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
oSh.ConnectorFormat.EndConnected
```

returns a boolean value indicating if the end is connected to something: check that before trying to access .EndConnectedShape

**NOTE:** it's worth spending some time to figure out how to use the Watch window to debug problems like this: if you set a watch on `oSh` then you can browse its propeties in the Watch window when you get an error, and look for likely avenues to explore...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much again! I knew that I need a True/False result, but my mind was too closed to look around EndConnected. Thanks! As for the Watch window, I was also trying to use it while debugging, but again unproperly - used intermediate variables and not the objects. Thanks again for teaching me as I'm a complete noob in VBA.